# While deploying mule application in tomcat or jetty , How to change http endpoints to servlet endpoints in configuration.xml file?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, mule, jetty

I have tried deploying basic mule application(using http listener connector) in tomcat and jetty and it worked.Here I changed the endpoints of http to ...

```xml
<servlet:inbound-endpoint path="sample"/>
<set-payload value="Hello mule!"/>
```

But now I'm trying to deploy other applications of mule, which uses inbuilt connectors like salesforce, I'm confused how to change the endpoints now.

For example this is how my config.xml file look.

[image: config.xml]

I'm using mule 4.3. Please guide/help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you do deploy a Mule 4 application into a servlet container first? Did it respond to HTTP requests?

Comment: I followed this link https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/deploying-mule-as-a-service-to-tomcat and added web.xml file and then packaged it into a war file using the maven command " maven package" and then deployed this into tomcat.

Comment: I'm surprised if that worked at all. Those instructions are for Mule 3 only. Mule 4 doesn't formally supports embedded deployments and has differences in design and libraries. It doesn't even has endpoints, only full connectors.

Comment: Then, we can't deploy mule 4 applications in app servers. If it supports in mule 3, how I have to change those endpoints?

Comment: What is the objective exactly? 'how to change the endpoints' is not very clear.

Comment: LIke, After changing the http endpoint to servlet, its getting reflected in mule flow(message flow), and the source connector(http listener) is getting removed. Then how will the flow get triggered? And how to process the data to message flow from transform message/payload of this config.xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Mule flow is triggered by a [message source](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/using-flows-for-service-orchestration#the-anatomy-of-a-flow). ie a ´connector´ that receives a request or message and starts the flow execution. When deploying the Mule application in a servlet container like Tomcat usually you would intend to receive HTTP requests from the container rather than using Mule own HTTP connector. That's the reason to use the [servlet endpoint](https://docs.mulesoft.com/servlet-connector/0.3.9/) to map requests from the container to flows.

Using it embedded you lose management options and some features. Built in libraries management is all manual so error prone. If you don't have a really good reason to deploy embedded I strongly recommend to use Mule standalone. For new projects you should be really using Mule 4.3 which is the current and modern version of Mule. All Mule 3.x releases are out of standard support period and no new improvements should be expected until the EOL.

Some connectors and endpoints are builtin in Mule 3.x (like the HTTP or SFTP connectors) and some need to be added to the project, like the Salesforce or SAP connectors. If you are using a Maven project you need to add the connectors dependencies.

Note that the Salesforce connector requires that you use the enterprise version of Mule and as I mentioned, Mule 3.x has more limited support at this time.